# How to call a method or directive inside interpolated strings?

Tags: vue.js

I want to log the value of the options on change.

The only problem is that I am using it inside string interpolation.

```
createStickyToolBox() {
      const fonts = ['Pacifico', 'VT323', 'Quicksand', 'Inconsolata', 'Times New Roman'];
      const options = fonts.map((font) => `<option value="${font}"> ${font} </option>`);
      const div = document.createElement('div');
      div.id = 'container';
      div.innerHTML = `<select id="test" name="form-select" ${options} </select>`;
      div.className = 'sticky-toolbox';
      div.style = `position: absolute; top: ${topOffset}px; left: ${leftOffset}px;`;
      document.getElementById('canvas-wrapper').appendChild(div);
    },
```

In the **innerHtml** element is the select tag with the options defined above. How can I access the values and log them for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the super-powers of `Vue.js` relies on its component-oriented architecture.

While your snippet above could, in theory, work, it doesn't benefit from the advantages that `Vue.js` has to offer as a framework.

A much cleaner approach, would be to create a `Vue.js` component:

```
<template>
  <div :style="{ top: topOffset + 'px', left: leftOffset + 'px' }" id="container">
    <select id="test" name="form-select">
       <option @change="log" v-for="option in options" :value="option">
          {{ option }}
       </option>
    </select>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  props: ['options', 'topOffset', 'leftOffset'];
  data() {return {};},
  methods: {
     log(event) {
        console.log(event.target.value);
     }
  }
};
</script>
<style scoped>
#id {
   positon: absolute;
}
</style>
```

And, in the parent component, use the children as follows:

```
<template>
  <div id="canvas-wrapper">
     <button @click="addContainer" type="button"> Add new container </button>
     <custom-container v-for="container in containers" :options="container.options" :topOffset="container.topOffset" :leftOffste="container.leftOffset"/>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import Container from './Container.vue';

export default {
  components: { Container },
  data() {
     return {
        containers: []
     };
  },
  methods: {
     addContainer() {
        let newContainer = {
            options: ['Pacifico', 'VT323', 'Quicksand', 'Inconsolata', 'Times New Roman'],
            topOffset: 5,
            leftOffset: 10,
        };
        this.containers.push(newContainer);
     }
  }
};
</script>
<style scoped>
#id {
   positon: absolute;
}
</style>
```